# Read Open Street Map xml response

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest, openstreetmap

Trying to read data from Open Street Map webpage. I have Longitude and Latitude. Based on these web link is generated.

Let's say output is:
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=48.927834&lon=16.861641&zoom=18&addressdetails=1

How to read webpage content? I have tried this but I am not getting anything in `result`.

```
  string urlString = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=48.927834&lon=16.861641&zoom=18&addressdetails=1";

  HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlString);
  myRequest.Method = "GET";
  WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
  string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
  sr.Close();
  myResponse.Close();
```

Getting:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.Net.Requests.dll
> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll

[image]

My target is to parse xml:

```
  // Loading from a file, you can also load from a stream
  XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(result);

  // Query the data and write out a subset of contacts
  IEnumerable<string> query = from c in xml.Root.Descendants("addressparts")
              select c.Element("road").Value + " " +
                     c.Element("house_number").Value;
```

Comment: What are the exception details?

Comment: You wrote you are getting a WebException.

Comment: Well, the exception is thrown but you are not catching it and the method ends with that exception. Put a try/catch in the method or check all CLR exception types in the exception settings window in visual studio.

Comment: @Steeeve added details

Comment: @Steeeve posted solution seems to be working. Maybe you can add it as an answer

Comment: maybe you could add the 'nominatim' tag, that was the real problem, not the xml-parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to provide a valid user-agent in your requests, otherwise the requests will be blocked. From the current [Nominatim Usage Policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/):

> - Provide a valid HTTP Referer or **User-Agent** identifying the application (stock User-Agents as set by http libraries will not do).

```
myRequest.UserAgent = "MyApp Version 1.2.3.4"
```